# How to reach variable from another page in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 function in different c++ files. I need reach one variable from another cpp file. How Can I do this?

I need reach `excelBuffer` located on `parser.cpp` on inside `void MainWindow::exportexcel()` function located on `mainwindow.cpp`

parser.cpp

```
void Parser::parse(QString inputString)
{
      
QStringList excelBuffer =inputString.split(",");// I need reach excell buffer 
qDebug()<< excelBuffer[1]; 
   
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::exportexcel() {
  
     //I need reach excelbuffer from here     
    }
```

Comment: How can I do this? Should I create same function on mainwindow or call function from parser.cpp?

Comment: You can't `excelBuffer` is local to `Parser::parse`. You are going to have to rethink your design, for example you could `return excelBuffer;` from `Parser::parse`, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this 2 ways. The first would be to change the signature of the function as suggested by @John in the comment section and the other would be to create a variable in the `Parser` class to hold the output of `parse` function.

**First way**

```
//in your header file

QStringList parser(QString inputString);

// in your cpp file

QStringList Parser::parser(QString input)
{
    QStringList excelBuffer =inputString.split(",");
    return excelBuffer;
}
```

**Second way**

First, you should create a public (depending on your OOP structure it might change) variable.

```
//in your header file
public:
    QStringList output;

// in your cpp file

void Parser::parse(QString inputString)
{
    QStringList excelBuffer =inputString.split(",");
    this->output = excelBuffer ;
}
```

Then you should create a variable of type Parser in the MainWindow class to reach its fields and attributes.

```
// in your MainWindow.h file 
Parser parser;

// In the function wherever you need

void MainWindow::exportexcel()
{
    for (QString b : parser.output)
    {
        qDebug() << b << "\n";
    }
}
```

Last comment,
I *personally* prefer to use the first approach since, *in my opinion*, it is more controlled, like in the second approach `output` variable can be changed in other functions too, you cannot simply be sure whether the `output` is the one `output` that you are looking for.

Comment: When I try to debug on mainwondow. I can not see all datas there is just some part of datas now comes totally complate.

Comment: So, now your problem is solved, right? If it is, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If `Parser` is a child of mainwindow simply do this:

```cpp
void Parser::parse(QString inputString)
{
    QStringList excelBuffer = inputString.split(u',');
    parent()->setProperty("exelBuffer", exelBuffer);
}
```

and in your MainWindow:

```cpp
void MainWindow::exportexcel()
{
    const QStringList exelBuffer = property("exelBuffer").toStringList();
}
```

and if `Parser` isnt a child of `MainWindow` use `qApp->property()` instead.