# Qt c++ How to reach QStringList from another functıon?

Tags: c++, qt

There are 2 functions from the same c++ file. first function one of the functions holds about two hundred thousand data. I want to send the data in my `QStringList` variable here to other functions. My aim is to be able to parse in other function and export to excel. How can I send this data accurately and completely to other function.

Here is function 1

```
void Parser::parse(QString inputString, )
{
     //I need store inputStringSplitArrayLines to buffer or etc for use for export to excel
       
    QStringList inputStringSplitArrayLines = inputString.split(QRegExp("[\\n+\\r+]"), Qt::SplitBehaviorFlags::SkipEmptyParts);
}


void Parser::parseExcel()
{
    //I want use stored data here/ How can I do this?
}
```

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73490310/how-to-reach-variable-from-another-page-in-qt-c)?  If the answers to that question don't solve the problem then you need to provide a lot more detail -- and preferably a [mcve].

Comment: How about returning the `QStringList` instead of a `void` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reach variable from another page in Qt C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73490310/how-to-reach-variable-from-another-page-in-qt-c)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: your list is global static (inline? what is c++ version) variable

```
// declare your list as static and global variable at the begging of file
static QStringList inputStringSplitArrayLines {};
//...
void Parser::parse(const QString &inputString)
{
    inputStringSplitArrayLines = inputString.split(QRegExp("[\\n+\\r+]"), Qt::SplitBehaviorFlags::SkipEmptyParts);
}
void Parser::parseExcel()
{
    //use inputStringSplitArrayLines as u want
}
```

Solution 2: your list is member of class `Parser`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).